# Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.07 extra spaces between characters using listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using SQL Developer 3.1.07 on an 11g database
When I use listagg to extract multiple values from a field I get a space between each character in the results for the listagg column. The query returns all the values I expect to see, it's just the extra spaces that are driving me nuts. Any thoughts?

Here is one query that I have used, but it happens everytime I use listagg in a query:

```
select a.personnum Emp_ID
      , a.personfullname Name
      , a.companyhiredtm Hire_Date
      , a.employmentstatus Status
      , a.employmentstatusdt Status_Date
      , h.Supervisor, h.Agency 
from vp_employeev42 a
  left outer join (select f.personid
                           , listagg (g.personcstmdatatxt, ',') within group  
                              (order by g.customdatadefid) Supervisor 
                    from vp_employeev42 f
                    left outer join personcstmdata g 
                        on f.personid = g.personid
                     where f.personnum like 'T%' 
                     and f.homelaborlevelnm3 = '1872'
                     and (g.customdatadefid = '1' 
                             or g.personcstmdatatxt is null)
                     group by f.personid) h
          on a.personid = h.personid
  left outer join (select f.personid
                      , listagg (g.personcstmdatatxt, ',') 
                              within group (order by g.customdatadefid) Agency
                   from vp_employeev42 f
                     left outer join personcstmdata g 
                           on f.personid = g.personid
                    where f.personnum like 'T%' 
                    and homelaborlevelnm3 = '1872' 
                    and (g.customdatadefid = '3' 
                              or g.personcstmdatatxt is null)
                      group by f.personid) h 
      on a.personid = h.personid   
where personnum like 'T%' 
and homelaborlevelnm3 = '1872' 
order by personnum;
```

Here are the results I get:

```
EMP_ID,NAME,HIRE_DATE,STATUS,STATUS_DATE,SUPERVISOR,AGENCY
T98999,Lxxxxm, Lxxxn,20-SEP-12,Active,20-SEP-12,, S t a f f m a r k

T98989,Fxxxxn, Dxxxxa,10-DEC-12,Active,10-DEC-12,, S t a f f m a r k

T99989,Hxxxs, Cxxxxxa,02-OCT-12,Active,02-OCT-12,, S t a f f m a r k
T99999,Hxxxs, Dxxxn,30-JAN-12,Terminated,21-MAY-12, C x x x x x x x x x r   T x x x x r, P R O L O G I S T I X
```

Comment: In future please post a *small reproducible* test case instead of a huge chunk of hard to understand code.  Apart from anything else, the act of boiling a problem down to its essentials often provides the solution, which is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

are you using `UTF-16` + `NVARCHAR2` by any chance? eg this:

```
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16

SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test(a nvarchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('test');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values ('test 2');

1 row created.

SQL> select listagg(a, ',') within group (order by 1) from test group by 1;

LISTAGG(A,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBY1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 t e s t, t e s t   2
```

you could cast to a char to get round this. IF this is not acceptible, you need to raise a ticket with Oracle support.

```
SQL> select listagg(to_char(a),',') within group (order by 1) from test group by 1;

LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(A),',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBY1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test,test 2

SQL>
```

Comment: That was the trick, I am using UTF-16 + NVARCHAR2 and using to_char did it. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently a known bug with no fix:

Bug 13501087 11.2.0.3 RDBMS 11.2.0.3 SQL EXECUTION PRODID-5 PORTID-226

Abstract: LISTAGG RETURN STRANGE DATA

```
*** 12/14/11 05:12 am *** (ADD: Impact/Symptom->WRONG RESULTS )

  SubComponent: SQL Analytics
  ===========================
  DETAILED PROBLEM DESCRIPTION
  ============================
  When using LISTAGG function  with NVARCHAR , data is returned with spaces
  between characters
```

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 12c I had the issue to with `LISTAGG` function. I used 
`ASCIISTR()` to get around it:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(TRIM(ASCIISTR(NVL(Name,''))), ';') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) AS Names
```

Works fine over here.