# Oracle data is returned with spaces between characters

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I am trying to retrieve data(select *..) from a SQL Server database to an Oracle database using dblinks. In my SQL Server database, I have a columns `AddressLine1` and `AddressLine2` of type `nvarchar`.

I am running the below script in SQL Developer (v 4.1.3.20). The results appear having spaces between characters. I used Benthic and SQL Plus and the results are same, spaces between characters.

```
SELECT 
    c.CandidateID,
    pa."AddressLine1", pa."AddressLine2"
FROM 
    CANDIDATES c --Oracle table
INNER JOIN 
    PostalAddress@HIM pa ON pa."EntityID" = c.CandidateID   -- SQL Server table
```

--@HIM --dblink name`

This screenshot shows the results (when copying blank spaces are copied):

[image: Results]

I also tried to cast the results to `varchar` and the results are same. I tried to trim the spaces and also tried to replace the whitespaces with NULL but the results remain the same.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So are you looking for a fix on the import side or maybe a query which can remove the extraneous whitespace?

Comment: if I had to guess I would guess characterset issues.  What is the character set for your oracle instance and for your sql server?  NVARCHAR means it won't do character set conversions

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wanted to know what causing this issue. A query that removes extra whitespace would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned earlier I tried using trim, to_char, regex_replace, replace functions but of no use.

Comment: @PeterM For Oracle it is AL16UTF16 and sql server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: try the convert function -- it might work?  select convert(address1,'AL16UTF16') from tab -- does that make a difference?  Is your column in oracle a VARCHAR2 or an NVARCHAR2?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304648/oracle-sql-developer-3-1-07-extra-spaces-between-characters-using-listagg

Comment: For now I created a temp table on SQL Server and inserted the nvarchar values by casting them to varchar. Then I used this new temp table to pull values from Oracle using dblinks.

Comment: Duplicate. Use `ASCIISTR()`, see: [stackoverflow.com/a/57836575/824622](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836575/824622)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does in fact appear to have something to do with the encoding.  Specifically, your text seems to be getting decoded using a character set where the width is two bytes, yet your ASCII data is only taking up one byte.

As a temporary fix, consider the following query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('6 2 1 1  W r i g h t s v i l l e  A v e', ' ([^ ])', '\1')
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

This outputs `6211 Wrightsville Ave`, which is what you want.  Note that I assume that every character has an extra ghost space, the result of which is that words which were originally separated by one space would now be separated by two spaces.

This isn't the best solution for so many reasons.  From a regex point of view, a much tighter answer could be given using lookarounds, but `REGEXP_REPLACE` does not appear to support them.