# spaces in the result of a listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

hello I have 2 database;

table1:IDSPUBPIPE

```
ID; ID1
1;1 
1;2 
1;3 
2;1 
3;3 
4;1 
5;2 
6;1
```

table2:IDSPUBCIRCUIT

```
    ID;NOM
1; test1
2; test2
3; test3 
4; test4 
5; test5 
6; test6
```

result hope

```
ID;ID1;nom
1;1,2,4,6;test1,test2,test4,test6
2;1,5;test1,test5
```

obtained result

```
ID;ID1;nom
1;1,2,4,6;t e s t 1 , t e s t 2 , t e s t 4 , t e s t 6 
2;1,5;t e s t 1 , t e s t 5 


select   cast(pipeci.ID as numeric) as ID, 
                    cast(pipeci.ID1 as numeric) as ID1, 
                    cast(RSF_cir.ID as numeric) as ID_circuit,
                    rsf_cir.NOM,
                    LISTAGG(RSF_cir.NOM, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pipeci.ID1, RSF_cir.NOM)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY pipeci.ID1) as Emp_list,
                    count(RSF_cir.ID) over(partition by pipeci.ID1)  as NB_circuit
            FROM IDSPUBPIPE pipeci
            LEFT JOIN IDSPUBCIRCUIT RSF_cir ON pipeci.ID=RSF_cir.ID
```

I don't understand the cause of the spaces between each letter, and I can't seem to find a solution
thank you in advance for your leads

[copieecran][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PipH1.jpg

Comment: Does the Ids contain `;` within it ? and the query you provided is not giving the expected result I believe. Please provide the actual query otherwise

Comment: not in any value; is not present

Comment: Please provide the query you are running which is producing the un-expected result ?

Comment: This should do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304648/oracle-sql-developer-3-1-07-extra-spaces-between-characters-using-listagg

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT p.ID1, 
       LISTAGG( r.ID,  ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.NOM ) as ID_circuit,
       LISTAGG( r.NOM, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.NOM ) AS Emp_list
FROM   IDSPUBPIPE p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN IDSPUBCIRCUIT r
       ON ( p.ID = r.ID )
GROUP BY p.ID1
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IDSPUBPIPE ( ID, ID1 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE IDSPUBCIRCUIT ( ID, NOM ) AS
SELECT 1, 'test1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'test2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'test4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'test5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'test6' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID1 | ID_CIRCUIT | EMP_LIST               
> --: | :--------- | :----------------------
>   1 | 1,2,4,6    | test1,test2,test4,test6
>   2 | 1,5        | test1,test5            
>   3 | 1,3        | test1,test3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31fd5cbadde61d7c596f35c928fec4ad)*